# Count number of increasing functions, nondecreasing functions $f: \{1, 2, 3, \ldots, n\} \to \{1, 2, 3, \ldots, m\}$, with $m \geq n$.

Tags: combinatorics, functions

I stumbled upon a question given like:

Let $m$ and $n$ be two integers such that $m \geq n \geq 1$.

Count the number of functions $$f: \{1, 2, · · · , n\} \to \{1, 2, · · · , m\}$$ of the following two types:

(a) strictly increasing; i.e., whenever $x < y, f(x) < f(y)$, and

(b) non-decreasing; i.e., whenever $x < y, f(x) \leq f(y)$.

I tried in the following way.

For (a). We can say $f(n)>f(n-1)$ AND $f(n)>f(n-2) \ldots f(n)>f(1)$ (total $n-1$ elements)

Similarly for $f(n-1)>f(n-2), f(n-1)>f(n-3) \ldots f(n-1)>f(1)$ (total $n-2$ elements)...

and $f(2)>1$

Like this $$(n-1) + (n-2) + \ldots + (1) = \frac{n(n-1)}{2}$$

Is this correct?

For (b). Since there's equality, it will be $$n + (n-1) + ... (1) = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$

Is my approach correct? Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: a strictly increasing function on a finite domain is uniquely determined by its image. A not necessarily strictly increasing function is not quite so, but it's close.

Comment: @Arthur Yes, that's why f(1)→f(1) is case 2 and I've considered it whereas in case 1 I didn't.

Comment: By the way, what does $f(1)\to f(2)$ really mean?

Comment: @Arthur When input is 1, the output is 2. Please help me, I'm learning.

Comment: Ahh. That would usually be written either $f(1)=2$ or $1\mapsto 2$. When you mean that $2$ is output, you would _never_ write $f(2)$. The place inside the parentheses is _always_ an input and never an output. But still, in the first case, $f$ _cannot_ map $1$ to $m$, because what would $f(2)$ be then?

Comment: @Arthur Ohh.. Ok! This is clear. Then will you clarify what f(x) < f(y) means?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57039/discussion-between-4py-and-arthur).

Comment: It means that the output of $f$ when given $x$ is strictly less than the output of $f$ when given $y$.

Comment: (I don't like discussions in chat, so I ignore that warning. I can't leave a discussion in chat for ten minutes and come back, while with comments that is possible. Right now I have to leave for at least a few hours quite soon, and in that case, chat is an even worse option.)

Comment: @Arthur No problem. :)
That means, when I give f(1), it can produce (m-1) outputs, right?
And this outputs will be large than f(2) if it has outputs > what f(1) produced? Similarly it will be for f(3)..f(n) when I fix a particular output for f(1)

Comment: $f$ being a strictly increasing function means exactly that its output when given $1$ (generically called $f(1)$) is strictly smaller than $f(2)$, its output when given $2$, which again is strictly smaller than $f(3)$, and so on. That means we cannot have $f(1)=5$ and $f(2)=3$ at the same time.

Comment: Oh, right, I think I know what you've misunderstood now: a function being increasing does _not_ mean that the output is greater than the input. It means that increasing the input necessarily increases the output.

Comment: @Arthur Well I'm still a bit foggy. Just tell me one thing. If we fix f(n). Then f(n) > f(n-1) again f(n) > f(n-2) .. f(n) > f(1). Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. At the same time, $f(n-1)>f(n-2)$ and $f(n-1)>f(n-3)$... $f(n-1)>f(1)$, all the way down to $f(2)>f(1)$.

Comment: @Arthur ok.. That means f(n) is greater than n-1 other functions.
f(n-1) is greater than n-2 functions...f(2) is greater than 1 function
So, 1+2+..(n-1) = n*(n-1)/2

Comment: @Arthur and for the `not strictly increasing` it will be 1+2+...n = n*(n+1)/2

Comment: @4py  I suggest that you edit your question in light of Arthur's feedback.  You should also include your revised attempts.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Edited with Arthur's feedback.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Thanks for editing. Everyone is so helpful here. :) From my future posts I'll, promise.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

> How many strictly increasing functions $f:\{1, 2, 3, \ldots, n\} \to \{1, 2, 3, \ldots, m\}$ are there?

A function $$f: \{1, 2, 3, \ldots, n\} \to \{1, 2, 3, \ldots, m\}$$ is determined by how the values $$f(1), f(2), f(3), \ldots, f(n)$$ are assigned.  Since $f$ is a strictly increasing function, 
$$f(1) < f(2) < f(3) < \ldots < f(n)$$
Thus, for a strictly increasing function, each value in the domain is mapped to a distinct element in the codomain.  Since there are $n$ elements in the domain and $m$ elements in the codomain, the number of ways we can select the elements in the range is $\binom{m}{n}$.  Once we have selected these elements, there is only one way to assign them so that the function is strictly increasing, namely by assigning the smallest element in the range to be $f(1)$, the next smallest to be $f(2)$, and so forth.  Hence, the number of strictly increasing functions is 
$$\binom{m}{n}$$

> How many nondecreasing functions $f: \{1, 2, 3, \ldots, n\} \to \{1, 2, 3, \ldots, m\}$ are there?

Since $f$ is a nondecreasing function, the function is completely determined by how many values of $j \in \{1, 2, 3, \ldots, n\}$ are assigned to equal $k \in \{1, 2, 3, \ldots, m\}$.  To see why, consider functions 
$$f: \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\} \to \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7\}$$
If two values are assigned to equal $3$, one value is assigned to equal $4$, and two values are assigned to equal $7$, then since $f$ is nondecreasing, $f$ must be the function defined by $f(1) = f(2) = 3$, $f(3) = 4$, $f(4) = f(5) = 7$.

Let $x_k$, $1 \leq k \leq m$, be the number of values of $j \in \{1, 2, 3, \ldots, n\}$ such that $f(j) = k$.  Then 
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + \ldots + x_m = n$$
which is an equation in the nonnegative integers.  A particular solution corresponds to the placement of $m - 1$ addition signs in a row of $n$ ones.

To make this concrete, consider nondecreasing functions 
$$f: \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\} \to \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7\}$$
Then we have 
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 + x_6 + x_7 = 5$$
The assignment 
$$+ + 1 1 + 1 + + + 1 1$$
corresponds to the above example that $x_1 = x_2 = 0$, $x_3 = 2$, $x_4 = 1$, $x_5 = x_6 = 0$, and $x_7 = 2$, that is, the function defined by $f(1) = f(2) = 3$, $f(3) = 4$, $f(4) = f(5) = 7$.  In this case, the number of such functions is the number of ways we can insert six addition signs in a row of five ones, which is 
$$\binom{5 + 6}{6} = \binom{11}{6}$$
since we must choose which six of the eleven symbols (five ones and six addition signs) will be addition signs.

By similar reasoning, the number of nondecreasing functions 
$$f: \{1, 2, 3, \ldots, n\} \to \{1, 2, 3, \ldots, m\}$$
is equal to the number of ways we can insert $m - 1$ addition signs in a row of $n$ ones, which is 
$$\binom{n + m - 1}{m - 1}$$ 
since we must select which $m - 1$ of the $n + m - 1$ symbols ($n$ ones and $m - 1$ addition signs) must be addition signs.

Comment: Excellent Explaination !!

Comment: Supreme.Well done

Comment: A note for readers: the counting technique used here for nondecreasing functions is called [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).

Answer (score 2):

A different approach for the non-decreasing case.

Set $F(n,m) = |\{ f : \{1, \ldots, n\} \to \{1,\ldots,m\} \mid f \mbox{ is non-decreasing. } \}|$. Then, $F(n,1) = 1$. Furthermore, we have the following recurrence relation:
$$
 F(n,m) = \sum_{i=0}^n F(n - i, m - 1). \quad (*)
$$
*Proof.* If $f : \{1,\ldots,n\} \to \{1,\ldots,m\}$ is non-decreasing,
set $k = |f^{-1}(1)|$.
Then, $f^{-1}(1) = \{1,\ldots, k \}$ (possibly empty)
and $f$ restricted to $\{ k + 1, \ldots, n \}$ (also possibly empty)
could be seen as a non-decreasing function from $\{k+1,\ldots,n\}$ to $\{2,\ldots,m-1\}$. For the restriction, we have $F(n - k, m - 1)$ many possibilities (the concrete naming of the numbers does not matter, just that they form a consecutive order) and each possibility is determined uniquely. Conversely, from any non-decreasing function $g : \{1,\ldots,n\}\to \{1,\ldots,m\}$ and $0 \le k \le n$ we can uniquely construct a non-decreasing function $f : \{1,\ldots,n+k\} \to \{1,\ldots, m+1\}$ by setting
$$
 f(x) = \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
 1        & 1 \le x \le k \\
 g(x) + 1 & \mbox{otherwise.}
\end{array}
\right.
$$
So, we have shown the recurrence equation. QED

Now, for the binomial coefficient, the following formula is valid:
$$
 \binom{m}{m} + \binom{m + 1}{m} + \binom{m + 2}{m} + \ldots + \binom{m + n}{m} = \binom{n + m + 1}{m+1},
$$
which is easy to prove by induction. Setting
$$
 G(n,m) = \binom{n + m - 1}{m-1},
$$
we see that $G$ fulfills Equation (*) above, and $G(n,1) = 1$. Hence, inductively, $F(n,m) = G(n,m)$.

A concrete example. Let $a < b < c$, then, non-decreaasing functions with codomain of size three could be interpreted as ordered strings over $\{a,b,c\}$. Then, for the domain of size three, we have the strings
$$
 aaa, aab, aac, abb, abc, acc, 
 bbb, bbc, bcc, ccc.
$$
I hope it could be seen how to construct these strings out of the ordered strings over $\{b,c\}$ of length at most three by appending runs of $a$'s in front of them.

Answer (score 0):

Problem with your approach is that function cannot map one number to multiple different numbers. On the other hand you can map multiple different numbers to one number.

Comment: Example of one function in a) case: f(1) = 2, f(2) = 3,..., f(n) = n + 1 (because m is bigger than n). Continue in that manner. Similar in b).

Comment: The question has been edited since you posted your answer.